# Rails4 polymorphic with self referencing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am quite new to Rails so this question might be a bit weird... I am building a system where I want `Users` to be able to leave `Feedback` regarding the other Users, but also regarding the `Item` they bought from them. Think of eBay feedback where they ask: *Were you pleased with the item?* and *Would you recommend working with Joe?*

Feedback model is obviously polymorphic since it can be of type `User` or `Item`

What I have is:

```
class User
    has_many :feedbacks, as: :feedbackable
end

class Item
    has_many :feedbacks, as: :feedbackable
end

class Feedback
    belongs_to :feedbackable, polymorphic: true
end
```

The problem I have with this is that Users are creators of the Feedback, but also the receivers (feedbackable) of the same feedback...

How do I achieve something like this:

```
class User
   has_many :feedbacks  # feedback.user
   has_many :feedbacks, as: :feedbackable   #feedback.feedbackable.type_id
end
```

In the sense that I can get all feedbacks that user A has left to other users and items and also all feedbacks that other users has left about the user A

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the politics of answering my own question, but I'll leave this answer here for anyone dealing with the same doubt...

For those of you who started reading about STI or many-to-many :through etc. it seems it's much easier to achieve this.

I ended up doing the following in the User model:

```
has_many :feedbacks
has_many :feedbacks_received, as: :feedbackable, :class_name => "Feedback"
```

Now I can do:

`user.feedbacks` and get all feedbacks that this user created (on Item or User)

and

`user.feedbacks_received` and get all feedbacks other users left about this user